# Can GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") really return null?

Tags: c#, windows, path, operating-system

This question may be a little less about C# and more about operating systems, please tell me if I should use other tags.

I need to find out if a user has Python installed, I thought checking for `python.exe` inside directories with "Python" in `PATH` was *good enough*, so I did:

```cs
string[] path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Split(';');
foreach (string directory in path)
{
    if (directory.Contains("Python")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thing is, `GetEnvironmentVariable` can return `null` and the responsible thing to do would be to make sure is not null before doing `Split()` and then putting it's value in `string[] path`.

But, really... is there any real scenario in which `GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")` would return `null`?

Comment: About a month ago, a friend of mine upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Guess what? He didn't have a `PATH`. I don't even understand how his system worked... oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I've even seen it in practice. I'm thinking it could only happen because of bugs or malicious behavior.

- Programs can change the environment of children by passing a parameter to `CreateProcess` and I suppose a bug or configuration issue could cause it to not set %path%. It is rare for programs to do this in the first place so it is an unlikely scenario.
- Build systems might erase everything to ensure reproducible builds but it would only stay in this state for a short while during startup and never propagate this environment to children.
- Someone playing around in cmd.exe and doing `set "path="` or running a buggy batch file. I find this to be the most likely scenario.

However unlikely, it would be a bit embarrassing for your app to crash with an exception because of this when you should be able to prevent it with an extra line or two of code...